# what is the deprecation policy of google's appsforyourdomain clients

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

It is clear that some of the client classes in the appsforyourdomain package are being deprecated by April 20th, 2015. I'm having trouble finding the deprecation status and replacement of these classes:

```
com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.AuditService 
com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.MailBoxDumpRequest 
com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.MailMonitor 
com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.AppsForYourDomainQuery 
com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.AppsPropertyService 
com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.NicknameService
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer : I am not a Googler but as a Google partner I work with those APIs every day. Here's my take on Google's communication. This is not an official Google communication.

Only some of the API called by these clients will be deprecated, the classes themselves were not covered by any service level and will not be, per se, deprecated.

- `AuditService` : the underlying Email Audit API is not deprecated. This class will still work after April 20th 2015.
- `MailboxDumpRequest` and `MailMonitor` : the underlying Email Audit API is not deprecated. This class will still work after April 20th 2015.
- `AppsForYourDomainQuery` and `NicknameService` : the underlying Provisioning API is replaced by the Directory API. [The relevant library can be found here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/libraries).
- `AppsPropertyService` : This class is involved in calls to two APIs depending on which child class you consider. There is the Provisioning API (`AppsGroupsService` child class) for which I have given the replacement library above. The other API is the Admin Settings API (for domain settings and SSO management). This API will still work after April 20th 2015.

Comment: The appsforyourdomain.audit.AuditService class seems to be documented here: 
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/. That page doesn't say it is being deprecated and the email-audit functionality doesn't seem to be replaceable by the Reports API.